# Is is possible to dynamically load a user control at runtime based on a condition within an UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net

I need to conditionally load a few nested user controls on a webpage based on a dropdown selection that fires a callback. Is this possible? Are there any best practices for such an approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like a [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf%28VS.80%29.aspx) method?